# Adding GPSIFD Pointer to an EXIF header without one

Tags: gps, jpeg, exif

I have special problem. I want to use lots of JPEG pictures with a predefined EXIF and add a GPS field.

The problem is that these pictures do not have already a Gps IFD. The EXIF is normally before the image data(SOI), so any modification of the EXIF would lead to a complete rewrite of the image in disk. I do not want to modify Gigabytes of pictures so that I add a GPS field.

1st Question: What are my options?

2nd Question: Can I overwrite a useless tag in the IFD0 with a `GPSInfoIFDPointer` to an offset after the SOI and then I would only need to append the GPSIF and data, which is an operation supported by FAT? Would this break most parsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as the resulting Exif data still fits within the APP1 JPEG segment, and it's still valid Exif, you can achieve what you're after. However if you have images from various sources you may find that you aren't able to always get your amended data to fit, as there might not be enough tags to remove in order to create the space required for a whole new IFD.

You cannot, unfortunately for you, create a pointer within the APP1 segment that points outside of the APP1 segment. Some readers might handle this, but it would be very irregular and likely cause problems. It's not something I've ever seen however.

If you can remove a few tags from existing IFDs, then you might have enough space to write your GPS IFD in the headroom you create.

You can also leave some dead space within the APP1 segment. That is, you don't have to make the new Exif data fit *exactly* within the space, it just cannot be any larger than what was there before.

Some JPEG consumers might allow you to move the APP1 segment to *after* the image segments (where you could extend the file from its end without re-writing/moving anything) but I haven't tried this so can't comment on how it'd work for you.

Comment: Hello Drew. That sounds what I was thinking. The critical information you gave me is that the new exif does not need to fill the complete space left from the deleted tags. My approach for now will be to get the thumbnnail out and if possible resize it. I will let you know how it turned out.

Comment: Good luck. It's an interesting problem and I'll be keen to hear how you get on.

Comment: Hello Drew. I did it. This is the file with the added GPS tag:http://www.filedropper.com/sonyilceqx101 and the original photo http://www.filedropper.com/sonyilceqx101_1
The method used libexif to load the exif from the original file, remove the thumbnail, add the GPS data and seek to the 'Exif' string position in the file. Rewrite the file with the new exif and memset the remaining space. I could resize the thumbnail but I am targeting an embedded system. The exercise of writing after the end of APP1 is still left. Thanks

Comment: The output looks good. Not sure you need to write anything after APP1 though, nor memset anything. A TIFF reader will ignore any bytes that aren't pointed to by tags or IFD pointers.